# Detecting Duplicates With a Linked List

Tags: c++, class, exception, linked-list

I am trying to convert an array set algorithm that would detect duplicate strings and throw out an error but instead of doing it in an array set, this time I am trying to implement it using a linked set. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here is my function when used in an array set:

```cpp
template<class ItemType>
void ArraySet<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newEntry) {
    if (std::find(std::begin(items), std::end(items), newEntry) != std::end(items))
    {
        throw DuplicateItemError(); 
    }  
    else 
    {  
        items[itemCount] = newEntry;
        itemCount++;
    }  
}
```

Here is my unmodified Linked Set function that I am trying to apply the same logic to but differently:

```cpp
template<class ItemType>
void LinkedSet<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newEntry) {
    Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr = new Node<ItemType>();
    nextNodePtr->setItem(newEntry);
    nextNodePtr->setNext(headPtr);

    headPtr = nextNodePtr;          // New node is now first node
    itemCount++;
}
```

Here is the class file as well:

```cpp
#ifndef LINKED_SET_
#define LINKED_SET_

#include "SetInterface.h"
#include "Node.h"

namespace cs_set {

    template<class ItemType>
    class LinkedSet : public SetInterface<ItemType>
    {
        private:
            Node<ItemType>* headPtr;
            int itemCount;

            // Returns either a pointer to the node containing a given entry
            // or nullptr if the entry is not in the bag.
            Node<ItemType>* getPointerTo(const ItemType& target) const;
   
        public:
            class ItemNotFoundError {};
            class DuplicateItemError {};
            LinkedSet();
            LinkedSet(const LinkedSet<ItemType>& aSet);
            virtual ~LinkedSet();
            int getCurrentSize() const;
            bool isEmpty() const;
            void add(const ItemType& newEntry);
            void remove(const ItemType& anEntry);
            void clear();
            bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
            //int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const;
            std::vector<ItemType> toVector() const;
    };
}

#include "LinkedSet.cpp"
#endif
```

SetInterface file:

```cpp
#ifndef SET_INTERFACE
#define SET_INTERFACE

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

namespace cs_set {
    template<class ItemType>
    class SetInterface
    {
        public:
           /** Gets the current number of entries in this bag.
            @return  The integer number of entries currently in the set. */
           virtual int getCurrentSize() const = 0;
   
           /** Sees whether this set is empty.
            @return  True if the set is empty, or false if not. */
           virtual bool isEmpty() const = 0;
   
           /** Adds a new entry to this set.
            @post  If successful, newEntry is stored in the set and
               the count of items in the set has increased by 1.
            @param newEntry  The object to be added as a new entry.
            @return  True if addition was successful, or false if not. */
           virtual void add(const ItemType& newEntry) = 0;
   
           /** Removes one occurrence of a given entry from this set,
               if possible.
            @post  If successful, anEntry has been removed from the set
               and the count of items in the bag has decreased by 1.
            @param anEntry  The entry to be removed.
            @return  True if removal was successful, or false if not. */
           virtual void remove(const ItemType& anEntry) = 0;
   
           /** Removes all entries from this set.
            @post  set contains no items, and the count of items is 0. */
           virtual void clear() = 0;
   
           /** Counts the number of times a given entry appears in this set.
            @param anEntry  The entry to be counted.
            @return  The number of times anEntry appears in the set. */
          // virtual int getFrequencyOf(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;
   
           /** Tests whether this set contains a given entry.
            @param anEntry  The entry to locate.
            @return  True if bag contains anEntry, or false otherwise. */
           virtual bool contains(const ItemType& anEntry) const = 0;
   
           /** Empties and then fills a given vector with all entries that
               are in this set.
            @return  A vector containing all the entries in the bag. */
           virtual std::vector<ItemType> toVector() const = 0;
   
           /** Destroys this set and frees its assigned memory. (See C++ Interlude 2.) */
           virtual ~SetInterface() { }
    };
}
#endif
```

Comment: `SetInterface<ItemType>` -- What is `SetInterface`?  And why is what you wrote going to be any different than simply using `std::forward_list<ItemType>` ?

Comment: SetInterface is my primary class, I forgot to include it

Comment: Iterate through the list and compare with the item to be added. If you find a duplicate, don't add it.

Comment: There's some very strong conventions laid down in the C++ Standard Library about naming and using iterators. Writing your own implementation of some container is fine from an educational point of view, but if you go and invent new names for things that already have names that's sort of missing the point. Tip: Write an iterator and use that to compare.

Comment: If you have a `begin()` and `end()` set up properly in your linked list, then it should work basically the same. You would just run `find()` through it, and add element if there isn't a duplicate

Comment: The `ArraySet` code suggests that `items` is a fixed-length array.  If so, then use of `std::end(items)` is wrong, it should be `std::begin(items)+itemCount` instead, otherwise unassigned elements will also be compared, which may cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like with an array, you need to iterate the linked list looking for a duplicate element.

If you have `std::begin()` and `std::end()` implemented for your `LinkedSet`, you can simply use `std::find()` the exact same way you do with `ArraySet` (that is why standard algorithms are designed to operate with iterators to begin with), eg:

```cpp
template<class ItemType>
void LinkedSet<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newEntry)
{
    if (std::find(std::begin(nodes), std::end(nodes), newEntry) != std::end(nodes))
    {
        throw DuplicateItemError(); 
    }  

    Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr = new Node<ItemType>();
    nextNodePtr->setItem(newEntry);
    nextNodePtr->setNext(headPtr);

    headPtr = nextNodePtr;          // New node is now first node
    ++itemCount;
}
```

Otherwise, if you don't have `begin()`/`end()` implemented, you can simply iterate the nodes directly instead, eg:

```cpp
template<class ItemType>
void LinkedSet<ItemType>::add(const ItemType& newEntry)
{
    for(Node<ItemType>* nodePtr = headPtr; nodePtr; nodePtr = nodePtr->getNext())
    {
        if (nodePtr->getItem() == newEntry)
            throw DuplicateItemError(); 
    }

    Node<ItemType>* nextNodePtr = new Node<ItemType>();
    nextNodePtr->setItem(newEntry);
    nextNodePtr->setNext(headPtr);

    headPtr = nextNodePtr;          // New node is now first node
    ++itemCount;
}
```